# Selecting a Video Encoder for Windows

Tags: video-encoding

My software encodes videos using the standard Windows AVIFile functionality. That means, it can use all the DirectShow Codecs that are installed.

I recommend my users to download the XVid Codec themselves, but that's inconvenient.
I cannot bundle XVid since my software is not GPL. Is there any good direct-show-compatible video codec that can be redistributed with a commercial application? Requirement: The videos must look great on YouTube.

If not, I could switch from AViFile to another library (e.g. FFMpeg). But I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Thanks! :-)

Edit: The videos are computer animation with very sharp details (explosions and sparks). The video should be high-bitrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Theora](http://www.theora.org) is an excellent open source codec with very good DirectShow support.  You also might consider google's newer [WebM](http://www.webmproject.org/) codecs.   You dont say what kind of video you are distributing (from a camcorder, animation/computer rendered graphics, etc), so some of the choice of codec may depend on the exact nature of your video.

Comment: Thanks! Bundling Theoras DirectShow filters might work, I'll look into that.

I'm also open for any other suggestions! :-)